# In javascript how do I multiple todays timestamp by four weeks

Tags: javascript

This is how I get todays timestamp:

```
var timestampNow = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
```

I want to set timestampNow to 4 weeks from now.

My initial guess is to use `Math.floor(Date.now(28) / 1000);`?

Comment: Do you mean add 4 weeks onto today's date?

Comment: When It Comes To Date Make Use Of MomentJS Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript isn't that great when it comes to dates, so you need to parse the date to a timestamp and modify the milliseconds. but the maths is not very hard.

```
var timestamp4weeks = Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4)
```

- milliseconds => seconds === `* 1000`
- seconds => minutes === `* 60`
- minutes => hours === `* 60`
- hours => days === `* 24`
- days => weeks === `* 7`

Comment: This works well for basic date math - but there are times when honoring DST is important: "I'll see you again at the same time, in 4 weeks." Simply adding the number of milliseconds will be an hour fast/slow if the 4 weeks spans a DST shift. It can also be a day off in leap years.

Comment: This is not adding 28 days. Instead it is adding (1000*60*69*24*28) ms which, as noted by @user2864740, is not the same thing (e.g. daylight savings, leap years, leap seconds).

Comment: > I want to set timestampNow to 4 weeks from now.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would work:

```
let fourWeeksFromNow = new Date();
fourWeeksFromNow.setDate(fourWeeksFromNow.getDate() + 28)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) makes this easy. The following are equivalent:

```
var days  = moment().add(28, 'days');
var weeks = moment().add(4, 'weeks');
```